# $K3$ surfaces in $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces, fano-varieties, automorphisms

I am considering $K3$ surfaces in $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ with an automorphism that preserves an ample divisor class.

For an automorphism $\rho$ of a $K3$ surface, let ${\rm Pic}^\rho(S) = \{ D \in {\rm Pic}(S) \mid \rho^*(D) = D \}$.

Let me state the question:

> For a given primitive ample divisor class $H$  of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$,
> does there exist a pair $(S, \rho)$ of  a smooth $K3$ surface $S$  that is an anti-canonical section of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 $ and an automorpism $\rho$ of $S$ such that
> $${\rm Pic}^\rho(S) = \left \langle H|_S \right \rangle?$$

According to Arnaud BEAUVILLE (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211313),  a $20-3=17$ dimensional family of $K3$ surfaces lie inside $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 $.
I do not see any obstacles which prevent such a pair from existing.

I guess that the Torelli theorem may help.

Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: What kind of automorphism?  There is an obvious cyclic automorphism of order $3$ of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ with rank $1$ invariant subgroup of the Picard group.,  It looks like the usual Noether-Lefschetz argument will give that a sufficiently general $(2,2,2)$-hypersurface that is stabilized by the automorphism will have the same Picard group (and will have $6$ fixed points).  However, if your automorphism is free on the K3 surface, obviously this forces the K3 surface to have "invariant Picard rank" equal to $10$.

Comment: @Jason star, no other requirements are put on, hence you answered the question!
Being excited by such a  quick answer, I changed the question a bit, which I would like to know the answer originally.

Comment: You added a hypothesis about a specified primitive ample divisor class.  For most choices of primitive ample divisor class, the answer is "no".  The normal bundle of the surface in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ is already one $\rho$-invariant divisor class.  If you specify another $\rho$-invariant divisor class that is not a (rational) multiple of the class of the normal bundle, then necessarily the "invariant Picard rank" is at least $2$.

Comment: Why is the normal bundle $\rho$-invariant?
Are you assuming that $\rho$ comes from an automorphism of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that the automorphism comes from $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$.  If the automorphism does not arise in this way, then there is no reason that the normal bundle should be $\rho$-invariant.

Comment: In the question, it is not assumed that $\rho$  necessarily comes from an automorphism of  $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ .

Answer (score 2):

In the generic case you'll have $\text{NS}(S)\otimes\mathbb R\cong\mathbb R^3$ and you can compute the $3$-by-$3$ matrix for the action of the three involutions $i_1,i_2,i_3$ on, say, a basis consisting of the three pullbacks of a point via the projections $\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3:S\to\mathbb P^1$. My recollection is that the eigen-divisors of infinite-order automorphsims such as $i_1\circ i_2$ are nef, but not ample, so they'll lie on the boundary of the ample cone. In other words, you may be able to get a nef eigen-divisor in $\text{NS}(S)\otimes\mathbb R$, but it seems unlikely you can get an ample eigen-divisor, at least when the picard number is $3$.

Comment: I also expect that such a K3 surface $S$  is not a generic one.
I simply would like to know whether such a K3 surface exists, regardless of generic or not.

Comment: @user69559 Fair enough, but you said that there is a 17-dimensional family of such surfaces (up to isomorphism) and that you "do not see any obstacles which prevent such a pair from existing," so I was noting that picard number 3 is probably an obstacle, so you'll need to look within the (countably many?) subfamilies of dimension 16 having picard number ${}\ge4$ for an example.